# conditional Page break in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am developing SSRS reports. For example, I have a value "PageBreak" in one of 
 the column called "HeaderDescp". Wherever i find a value "PageBreak" in the column  HeaderDescp,  Report has to go to next page. If there is no page break found it should fit into the page itself.

Thanks

WHERE TO TRY THE BELOW Code? SHOULD I CREATE A GROUP ?

Answer (score 0):

```
=IIF(Parameters!PageBreak.Value,Fields!MyField.Value,"")
```

Try this one.create a boolean parameter and give it default value(optional)